# Последовательный вызов методов vkapi в jssdk

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Передо мной стоит следующая задача:

Необходимо позволить пользователю при нажатии кнопки на сайте запостить на стену нечто и получить за это награду в ответ.

Звучит просто, но я столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Для корректной работы метода `wall.post` необходимо, чтобы приложение сайта было установлено у пользователя. Соответственно перед методом `wall.post` вызывается метод `auth.login`. И вот тут как раз начинаются проблемы. Браузер блочит всплывающее окно с `wall.post`, если вызвать метод из колбека логина. По отдельности на реальные клики все замечательно, но клик, все же, должен быть один по задаче.

Пробовал так же вызывать событие клика множеством разных способов, результат без изменений. Быть может я не в том проблему ищу и причина блокировки всплывающего окна в другом?

Comment: Приложите код, иначе всё что Вы рассказали не имеет смысла